# Build IPA through PhoneGap CLI and allow push notifications

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-cli

I'm able to generate an .ipa file through Phonegap's CLI (iOS version 3.9.2) by running the following command:

```
phonegap build ios --save --device
```

I'm also adding the provisioning profile UUID in the config.json file by adding the following:

```
"ios": {
    "release": {
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Distribution",
      "provisioningProfile": "superSecretDoubleProbation!"
    }
  }
```

This works well for creating .ipas that we can install, but it does not prompt for getting push notifications, which leads me to believe the APNS cert is not getting loaded into the bundle, ergo not making the call upon launch. (It does so if I install it through `phonegap build ios --device`.

Is there a way to include it as part of the build, or is that not supported?

Thanks in advance!